# Serving Static Workspace Files in Oracle APEX with Javascript

Tags: javascript, oracle, image, url, oracle-apex

I am incorporating [browser notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification) into Oracle APEX and I'm having trouble showing a custom icon in the notification. These icons can be adjusted to your liking by providing a URL to the location of the image. In Oracle APEX, you can upload static files and reference them using the #WORKSPACE_IMAGES#image.png, however, the #WORKSPACE_IMAGES# part does not get replaced when I use it in JavaScript. **How do I get the URL of a static workspace file (png image) in JavaScript?** I have tried using the following strings for the URL parameter of the notification:

```
showNotification(
    // "https://developers.google.com/web/images/web-fundamentals-icon192x192.png", // Works
    // "r/xxxxx/files/static/v71/image.png",                                        // Works, but is subject to change
    // "#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#image.png",                                               // Does not work
    // "&WORKSPACE_IMAGES.image.png",                                               // Does not work
    // "#IMAGE_PREFIX#image.png",                                                   // Does not work
    // "&IMAGE_PREFIX.image.png",                                                   // Does not work
    notification.title,
    notification.body,
    () => parent.focus()
);

const showNotification = (icon, title, body, onclick) => {
    // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
        alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
    }

    // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
    else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        // If it's okay let's create a notification
        let notification = new Notification(title, {
            icon: icon,
            body: body,
        });

        notification.onclick = onclick;
    }

    // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
    else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
        Notification.requestPermission();
    }
};
```

**These work:**

- https://developers.google.com/web/images/web-fundamentals-icon192x192.png
- r/xxxxx/files/static/v71/image.png (the URL of the image once I rendered it normally using an APEX Image Display Item)

**These don't:**

- #WORKSPACE_IMAGES#image.png
- &WORKSPACE_IMAGES.image.png
- #IMAGE_PREFIX#image.png
- &IMAGE_PREFIX.image.png

**Extra information**

- We are using Oracle APEX 20.2 on an Autonomous Database

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
I ended up uploading the image to a domain handled by a hosting provider so I can access the image via that url.

Answer (score 0):

Replacements such as `#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#image.png` should work fine from Javascript - but only if that Javascript is rendered by APEX as part of the page, **not** if the Javascript is in a separate file.  For example:

[image]

When the page is run:

[image]

Comment: This answer is useful, and I know that it works this way. However the notification is not really rendered on the page. It is rendered by windows. So that is why the replacement is not working. I ended up using uploading the image to a hosted domain and acces the image from there.

Comment: I know the notification is not rendered on the page.  But the Javascript to call alert *is* rendered on the page (when using APEX page Javascript as in my answer) and hence APEX converts `#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#` to the real path before rendering the page.